# How to add ScrollPane to main stage

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I'm interested how I can add `ScrollPane` to the main stage. I want when I reduce the size of the main page to use `ScrollPane` to move over the main stage. Is there any example?

Answer (score 3):

If your content of the `ScrollPane` is larger than the allowed size of the `ScrollPane`, the `ScrollPane` should automatically attach scrollbars.  Here's an example:

```
public class JFXScroll extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        BorderPane main = new BorderPane();

        ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane();
        VBox box = new VBox();

        // Demo purposes; Wouldn't normally do this - just let the box automatically fit the content
        box.setPrefSize(1000, 500);
        box.setEffect(new ColorInput(0,0,1000,500,Color.LIME));

        scroll.setContent(box);

        main.setLeft(new Label("Left Content"));
        main.setCenter(scroll);

        Scene scene = new Scene(main, 300, 250);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();


    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`stage.setScene(new ScrollPane(yourContent));` should do it.
Of course your content should have an appropriate min, max and preferred sizes